# Пути до файлов {WEB}

Tags: html

День добрый, сижу я значит выпиваю всвязи с наступившими выходными и тут в голову попал следующий вопрос:
Предположим я подключаю CSS файл как правильнее указывать путь

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```

или же:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://domain/css/style.css">
```

такой-же вопрос с картинками и другими файлами =)

Comment: в зависимости от ситуации. Смотря где Ваша картинка/css находиться. В первом случае css будет искаться в корне сервера.

Comment: @KoVadim это все понятно, так или иначе в обоих случаях оба работают, но как правильнее =) с точки зрения поисковиков там, загрузки страницы и так далее

Comment: я бы брал первый вариант - объем текста получается меньше. Если захочется перенести на новый домен, то ничего не нужно менять. Но если картинка/css находится на другом сервере/домене, то тут уж ничего не поделаешь, придется указывать полный путь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд относительные пути предпочтительнее всегда за исключением CDN, понятное дело. Как минимум Вы не привязаны к конкретному хосту, проще запускать из другого места, например.

Comment: А если я предположим вместо "domain" отдаю <?=$domain;?> в данном случае необходимо будет домен прописать один раз =)
Вопрос по факту без смысла к решению задачи, просто интерес и алкоголь делают свои дела.